# Finding a basis for this subspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$W = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & x\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c\in \mathbb{C},x\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
with the usual matrix addition and scalar multiplication. Note that the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the subspace of $W$:
$$U = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&x\end{pmatrix}\in W: a-b+2x=0\right\}.$$

How would I find a basis for $U$?

Firstly, I used the condition in $U$ so I have $a = 2x+b$.

So $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&x\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2x+b&b\\c&x\end{pmatrix}$$

And I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$$\begin{pmatrix}2x+b&b\\c&x\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\Re(b)\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\Im(b)\begin{pmatrix}i&i\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+\Re(c)\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+\Im(c)\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\i&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Edit: As for finding the dimension of $U$ without finding a basis, you can show that there is a rank $2$ linear transformation $T:W\to \Bbb C$ such that $U=\ker T$. Apply rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I think I was confused because my solutions showed it differently, and I had no idea how to form their basis vectors using linear combinations of those.

Comment: Also how did you (if you did) know that the dimension must be $5$ (I'm referring to your other comment), without calculating it first?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

write your last  matrix as

$$xM_1+bM_2+cM_3$$

and prove that $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are linearly  independent.

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, many different answers to this because any space has an infinite number of bases.
 You have written a generic member of this subspace as $\begin{pmatrix} 2x+b & b \\ c & x\end{pmatrix}$.  That can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}2x & 0 \\ 0 & x\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ c & 0\end{pmatrix}= x\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ c\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

One basis is $\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \}$

Comment: This is not a basis, because the dimension of $U$ should be 5.